# What might cause a Delphi program to 'prevent Windows shutdown'?

Tags: delphi, system-shutdown

One of my Delphi XE2 programs, when running and idle, 'prevents Windows shutdown'.  This is not the case with most of my applications and I need to resolve it.  On XP, Windows silently fails to close; on Win7 the dialog shows my application preventing shutdown.

Unlike the similar questions here, the program is single-threaded, I am not using the tray, and I have temporarily disconnected the OnCloseQuery and FormClose events in the main form and the one subsidiary form that had them. In normal use the program closes cleanly and no trace of it remains in Process Explorer.

I have experimemtally added WM_QueryEndSession and WM_EndSession handlers which write a log message to the Windows Event log.  On a test Windows shutdown, only the former fires, with Wparam and Lparam both zero.

I would be most grateful for any ideas on what could be causing this, or for how to investigate it further.  I am reluctant to try a call to Halt on the WM_QueryEndSession without knowing what is going on.

Comment: You can implement WM_QueryEndSession and call Application.Terminate

Comment: Why won't your program close when windows tells it to?

Comment: @David: that is exactly what I am trying to discover!

Comment: Can you make an SSCCE?

Comment: An SSCCE would be hard, because (a) most of my applications do not behave in this way, and (b) adding complexity until it fails may involve many tedious reboots.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: that would leave my app dead if a later app rejects the end session and the user decides to continue the session.

Comment: @frogb if your app returns `true` for `WM_QueryEndSession` then it will receive `WM_EndSession`, even if a later app (or the user) decides afterward to interrupt the shutdown.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to get to work to make the SSCCE.

Comment: My app does set result to true in WM_QueryEndSession (tried with and without then calling inherited, which also sets result to true). But my WM_EndSession handler does not fire for this app.

Comment: How to create the SSCCE: Leave the 'problem program' running: we know it will block any session shutdown. And open Delphi help: DEXPLORE will block Delphi from closing.  Finally, keep adding to the SSCCE until it fails; while it does not fail, Delphi will not close and nor will the machine shut down, avoiding the need to wait for a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final state where it was failing, the program had the FormCloseQuery methods reconnected, but in each one it was now checking a 'shuttingdown' global boolean, and allowing close if this was set.  Shuttingdown was set to true in a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message handler on the main form. This works for single-form applications.

The problem was caused by the fact that the FormCloseQuery handlers for other than the main form are all called before the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message handler on the main form.  I had missed this fact in the various edits and tests that I had been making.

If your application has any subsidiary form which has a FormCloseQuery handler, in which the result might be 'do not close' if it is called at a random moment (e.g. at end session, when the form might not have been initialized) then you require a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message handler **in each such form**.  This can then set a form or local variable to cause FormCloseQuery to set canclose to true.

Comment: I had a similar case. An OnFormCloseQuery of a secondary form was preventing the whole application to be shut down. Remarkable is that this form was created at runtime but never shown. So the defect was not obvious because the close query will be performed for every existing form, not only for those showing. In my case an unproperly initialized variable was the culprit.